# Getting exception while creating Lucene indexer using DotNetRDf.Query.FullText

Tags: .net-core, jena, lucene.net, fuseki, dotnetrdf

Hi I am trying to use DotNetRDf.Query.FullText in .Net core 3.1 to create Lucene indexer but getting below run time exception. Can you please help to resolve this issue?

> System.TypeLoadException   HResult=0x80131522   Message=Could not load
> type 'MaxFieldLength' from assembly 'Lucene.Net, Version=4.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=85089178b9ac3181'.

Sample Code:

```
var indexer = new LuceneObjectsIndexer(new RAMDirectory(), new StandardAnalyzer(LuceneVersion), new DefaultIndexSchema());
```

Package Version Used:
DotNetRDF - 2.1.6
Lucene - 4.8.0-beta00013

Comment: Can you provide a full stack trace for this exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something seems odd about this.  Lucene.net 3.x had a `MaxFieldLength` type that could be passed in an `IndexWriter` constructor but Lucene.net 4.X has no such type and it's `IndexWriter` class has no constructor that accepts such a parameter.

See [Lucene.net 3.03 ImageWriter class](https://github.com/mono/lucene.net/blob/3.0.3-2/src/core/Index/IndexWriter.cs) and compare that to [Lucene.net 4.8 ImageWriter class](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/Lucene.Net_4_8_0_beta00013/src/Lucene.Net/Index/IndexWriter.cs)

So it feels like the the DotNetRdf library may have been written to depend on a `ImageWriter` constructor that is only available in a 3.X version of Lucene.  If you show a full stack trace that may help shed more light on the situation.

Looking at the [dotnetrdf.org](https://www.dotnetrdf.org/) site I didn't see where they document what version of Lucene they use, but this error makes it pretty clear the library is designed for Lucene.Net 3.x.   I'd recommend trying to use the [`Lucene.Net 3.03` Nuget packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net/) rather than the 4.8 beta packages and see if that resolves your issues.

Comment: I'm one of the maintainers of dotNetRDF and I can confirm that Ron is correct, the current version of dotNetRDF uses Lucene.net 3.0.3. I've created [this ticket](https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/issues/359) to track the work needed. Any support / PRs most welcome!

Comment: Tried using Package Version: DotNetRDF - 2.1.6 Lucene - 3.0.3 but getting same error. Stack Trace -    at VDS.RDF.Query.FullText.Indexing.Lucene.BaseSimpleLuceneIndexer..ctor(Directory indexDir, Analyzer analyzer, IFullTextIndexSchema schema, IndexingMode mode)
   at VDS.RDF.Query.FullText.Indexing.Lucene.LuceneSubjectsIndexer..ctor(Directory indexDir, Analyzer analyzer, IFullTextIndexSchema schema)

Comment: It's hard to believe you get the same exception using Lucene 3.0.3 since it definitely declares a MaxFieldLength type.  To verify it works I used Visual Studio 16.8.3 to create a web application, full framework 4.61, mvc, and installed dotNetRDf 2.6.1 (which is the latest version NOT 2.1.6) via nuget, and it auto installed Lucene 3.0.3 as a dependency, I didn't need to do that separately.  I then executed the line of code you specified in the question with Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30 as the `LuceneVersion` and ran the code.  It worked without issue. I can email you a zip of the project.